# jQuery - clone and append to textarea

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone a div and then I want to append it to a textarea  when a button get clicked.
But for some reason when I click on button I see:

```
[object Object]
```

Here is my code:

```
$('#save').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var new_layout = $("#layout-builder").clone();
    jQuery('#for-save').append(new_layout); // also tried val()
});
```

Please tell me how do I clone a div and append it to a textarea

Answer (score 2):

use `.html()`

```
jQuery('#for-save').append(new_layout.html());
```

or to append outerHtml

```
jQuery('#for-save').append(new_layout[0].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using clone() this can not be copied to text area. this more detail [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)
and change append to val()

so please change your code into:

```
$('#save').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var new_layout = $("#layout-builder").html();
  jQuery('#for-save').val(new_layout);
});
```